# Paypal IPN get empty POST data

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the sandbox environment and the code for my IPN listener is from https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

After the sandbox transaction complete, I get empty `$_POST` while receive `$_GET` instead.

```
Array
(
     [tx] => 14M290096L261713C
     [st] => Pending
     [amt] => 1.00
     [cc] => USD
     [cm] => 
     [item_number] => 
)
```

It's confusing me because it's not safe passing data using `GET` method. I've changed the button encoding language to `utf-8` and my listener passed the IPN simulator.

After searching any possible solution online I found [this blog article](http://www.geekality.net/2010/10/19/php-tutorial-paypal-payment-data-transfers-pdt/), and in the tutorial it received `$_GET` data as well. It makes me wonder if it's also a suggested way to do IPN listening using `GET`.

Here's my Paypal button code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="A5HMGXMJNWR7Y">
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Plan">Plan</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
        <option value="Basic">Basic $1.00 USD</option>
        <option value="Advacned">Advacned $2.00 USD</option>
        <option value="Premium">Premium $3.00 USD</option>
    </select> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Did I miss something? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while for me, but `IPN` is **not** `PDT`, the blog article is `PDT`.

Which/when to use [`PDT` and/or `IPN`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/)

See [IPN info/detail here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

The key items to understand about IPN are:

> IPN is an **asynchronous** message service, meaning that *IPNs are not synchronized with actions on your website*....
>
> The IPN message service is not a real-time service. As a result, your listener may not receive an IPN message for many seconds after an event occurs. As a result, *your checkout flow should not depend upon receiving an IPN message to complete*. If it does, your checkout flow will be slow during periods of heavy system load and complicated, since it must handle retries.

hth..